# Do the web servers for those websites deliberately block accesses from IPs in PRC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand a problem that I often encounter from the perspective of server administrators.

I am visiting the Internet under the censorship of the Great Firewall in PRC. I found that some websites seem to refuse my visits.

For example, when I visited https://www.avogel.co.uk/health/enlarged-prostate/worst-foods-for-an-enlarged-prostate/

> 403 ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from
> your country. We can't connect to the server for this app or website
> at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration
> error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner. If you
> provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to
> troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront
> documentation.
>
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
>
> Request ID: FEC4Gx3yJUaRwLv4RVA7CUJ-rb26nzBi1BEgaxqlAOO0VTQiTyN0mw==

When I visited https://www.healthline.com/health/enlarged-prostate/bph-and-caffeine

> 403 ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or
> website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
> configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website
> owner.
>
> If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find
> steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the
> CloudFront documentation.
>
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
>
> Request ID: bD5Kp3zdG6G4XBr1t7mdbGlwfpVkNXxdqRU5P7g8X6iAk3GNbXXPsg==

I am not sure I understand the messages.
Do the web servers for those websites deliberately block accesses from IPs in PRC?

What can I do to access such websites?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront supports [geo-blocking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html). CloudFront returns `403 (Forbidden)` if no custom error message is defined when a request comes from a blocked region.

> Do the web servers for those websites deliberately block accesses from IPs in PRC?

Likely deliberately. CloudFront supports include and exclude lists. So a website can also be configured to just allow requests from a defined list of countries.

Comment: Thanks. The PRC government blocks people in PRC from accessing many websites on the Internet, for political purposes, with which many strongly disagree.  Why would some websites (including those that provide information that can be beneficial to the entire human race) block accesses from IPs in PRC?

Comment: @Tim: `Why would some websites (including those that provide information that can be beneficial to the entire human race) block accesses from IPs in PRC?` To avoid/make it more difficult for the infinite deluge of attacks that egress from China IP netblock allocations.

Comment: @GregAskew The other websites (including the obvious targets like the US government websites) don't block accesses from PRC, and is that because they can handle the attacks? Is PRC worth being treated differently? The majority of the people here don't  want to and know how to attack. For those who attack, they probably have already knew ways to bypass the blocking, using VPN, etc

Comment: @Tim: This isn't a forum that will be able to document all of the differences in the world why some entities block China and others do not.